# Spring integration with multiple executor channel not processing in parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have  requirement where  i need to pass message to multiple channels asyc. To make my flow asyc i am using all executor channel. But for some reason flow is still sequential. i can seen diff thread as i configured in task executor but in sequence.
Here is the configuration I am using

```
<int:channel id="mainChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel1"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel2"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3"/>
      
</int:interceptors>
    </int:channel> 
   <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec1" />
   </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="channel2">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec2" />
  </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec3" />
  </int:channel>
```

As per my understanding all this will be asyc (in my case 3 thread should run in parallel)

from log i can see all sequential but with diff thread name..
I am assuming preSend/Postsend should have been called in random order.

am i missing anything to make multiple executor channel in parallel.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from log i can see all sequential but with diff thread name

Because logs are just a single place where messages are printed and they really are printed by one writer even if from different thread. They are appear over there one by one. With a good load you would definitely see that messages are logged in an unexpected order.

> I am assuming preSend/Postsend should have been called in random order.

That's not true. Interceptors are called in an order how they are added to the channel and if their `order` is the same, which is a case for you. It is already not an interceptor chain responsibility how those interceptors are implemented.

I think you just were not lucky to see logs in arbitrary order and probably just because consumers for those executor channels are plain loggers - no any loads to hold the thread and have an impression that work in other threads is done in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Artern. when I have more messages I can see in arbitrary order. I have another question if you can help on that. i have requirement to block the main thread until all  the async tasks complete but this async tasks are not same all the time e.g say for one thread i have only 2 async tasks and for another i thread i have 3  async. Any advise?

Comment: This sounds more like a new SO thread. Please, learn how to ask here for better context tracing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can raise that thread and ping me here, if I won't be notified for a new `spring-integration` question earlier.

Comment: thanks for reply posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079094/block-main-thread-with-multiple-executor-channel

Answer (score 1):

You might need to call the async implementation bean as shown:

```
<beans:bean id="asyncExecutor"
            class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

---

```
   <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="asyncExecutor" />
   </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="channel2">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="asyncExecutor" />
  </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="asyncExecutor" />
  </int:channel>
```

Description of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor:

> public class SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor extends CustomizableThreadCreator
> implements AsyncListenableTaskExecutor, Serializable
>
> TaskExecutor implementation that fires up a new Thread for each task,
> executing it asynchronously.
>
> Supports limiting concurrent threads through the "concurrencyLimit"
> bean property. By default, the number of concurrent threads is
> unlimited.
>
> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a
> thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for
> executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

Example Of Usage from Github:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <channel id="taskExecutorOnly">
        <dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="failoverFalse">
        <dispatcher failover="false"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="failoverTrue">
        <dispatcher failover="true"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="loadBalancerDisabled">
        <dispatcher load-balancer="none"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="loadBalancerDisabledAndTaskExecutor">
        <dispatcher load-balancer="none" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="roundRobinLoadBalancerAndTaskExecutor">
        <dispatcher load-balancer="round-robin" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="lbRefChannel">
        <dispatcher load-balancer-ref="lb"/>
    </channel>

    <beans:bean id="taskExecutor"
                class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>

    <beans:bean id="lb"
                class="org.springframework.integration.channel.config.DispatchingChannelParserTests.SampleLoadBalancingStrategy"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/src/reference/asciidoc/configuration.adoc#namespace-taskscheduler