# Block main thread with multiple executor channel

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-integration

I have a multithreading project where I read a message from a queue and pass it to spring integration to process it. Each messages goes though diff channel end up storing in DB and sending to downstream Qs.

```
<int:channel id="mainChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel1"  selector-expression="!headers['somevalue']"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel2"   selector-expression="!headers['somevalue']"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3"   selector-expression="!headers['somevalue']"/>
      
</int:interceptors>
    </int:channel> 
   <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec1" />
   </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="channel2">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec2" />
  </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec3" />
  </int:channel>
```

Now I want to block the sender thread until all the async tasks are finished processing e.g say in thread one only message goes to all channel(1,2,3) and for another thread it will go to only 2 channel (1,2) and so on.

I have seen aggregator/Thread barrier approach but not sure how it will work since for each thread flow will be diff.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threading doesn't matter; the main thread calls the barrier and whichever thread adds the 3rd message to the aggregator will release the group which can then be used to trigger the barrier.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#barrier

Comment: That is issue, its not guarantee all the 3 channel will execute all the time, that channel invocation is based on the header value for each thread.

Comment: I don't see how, since all 3 selector expressions are the same. If they can truly go to a variable number of subflows, you can use a custom release strategy in the aggeregator to determine when the group is complete.

Comment: See `RecipientListRouter`: it has the same `selector` feature and also an `applySequence` option to satisfy downstream aggregator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter

Comment: Artern, this solution sounds good to me, just to confirm do i need to aggregate the response? if yes how i can i do? i cant find any example where we are using RecipientListRouter with aggregator. thanks

Comment: just to add, all my channels will be executor channel in Recipient list

Comment: i am able to block the thread using aggregator and RecipientListRouter.